# Text of Birkat Hachodesh

Tags: tefilla, nuschaot, nusach-ashkenaz, text

In the standard Ashkenazi version of the siddur, we have in the birkat hachodesh: שֶׁתְּחַדֵּשׁ עָלֵינוּ אֶת הַחדֶשׁ הַזֶּה לְטובָה וְלִבְרָכָה. וְתִתֶּן לָנוּ...חַיִּים שֶׁאֵין בָּהֶם בּוּשָׁה וּכְלִמָּה...

I remember reading that there is a variant version which reads (something like): 
חַיִּים שֶׁיש בָּהֶם בּוּשָׁה וּכְלִמָּה

Does anyone know where the latter version can be found and/or the history of it?

Comment: Note that that text is a) originally a Talmudic prayer for after Shemoneh Esrei, b) was not in any "standard Ashkenazi" Siddur till maybe 200 years ago.

Comment: interesting article on the prayer (not any answer to your question): https://beureihatefila.com/files/2010-06-25_Tefila_Newsletter.pdf

Comment: The original text in Berachos 16b has שאין בהם, FWIW.